# Application closed when using Socket.IO via SocketIO4NET by WCF duplex channel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, socket.io

I use [SocketIO4Net](http://socketio4net.codeplex.com/) for connecting to [Socket.IO](http://socket.io) with C#, but when I try to emit an object to clients, my C# application suddenly gets closed (I have an MVC3 project)

I read Event Viewer and there's 3 errors:

1)

```
A Webhost unhandled exception occurred.
 Sender Information: System.AppDomain/26995560
 Exception: System.Runtime.FatalException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

2)

```
An unhandled exception occurred and the process was terminated.

Application ID: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT

Process ID: 3696

Exception: System.Runtime.FatalException

Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

3)

```
Application: w3wp.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Runtime.FatalException
Stack:
   at System.Runtime.Fx+IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)
   at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)
```

What's wrong with my project? Is there any bug in SocketIO4NET?

Comment: Can you update code that you have tried.

Comment: @NarendraV: I can't give you a sample code because I have a big project and really I don't know where/when problem occurred.

Comment: I'd take a look further if you can give something concrete to go on (author of SocketIO4Net). You've posted a generic set of errors that could have been triggered by any number of things...

Comment: And this had zero to do with SocketIO4Net - so many thanks for cleaning that up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found answer, this is because the version of .NET (I use .NET 4) and the WCF duplexChannel.

You should add this attribute on the top of WCF wrapper class:

```
[CallbackBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext=false)]
```

Thanks to Cauldwell.net for the answer: http://www.cauldwell.net/patrick/blog/CategoryView,category,CodeGen.aspx

From cauldwell.net:

> The problem, it turned out, was that ASP.NET uses (by default) a
>   little thing called the SynchronizationContext. As near as I can tell
>   (I haven't researched this thoroughly, to be honest) one of it's jobs
>   it to make sure that any callbacks get run on the UI thread, thereby
>   obviating the need to call Control.Invoke like you do in WinForms. In
>   my case, that additional lock was giving something fits, and it was
>   trying to clean stuff up on a thread that wasn't around any more,
>   hence to NullReferenceException.

Special thanks to [James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82696/james)